# Debugging external dll with Delphi

Tags: delphi, debugging, dll

I would like to look at real symbols for an external dll compiled with bcc (bcc32) inside Delphi debugging. The problem is that it seems that bcc only allows externals symbols (tds file) and delphi does not see this symbols. So is there a way to force bcc32/ilink32 to embed symbols inside the dll or Delphi to understand dll with tds symbols?

Thank you,

Max

Answer (score 2):

Try your project using C++ Builder: that allows you to integrate your Delphi and C++ code in one project (or have multiple projects in one project group: a C++ DLL and a Delphi host).

Since they use the same debugging format, it is way easier to debug.